# Cannot select bottom row in a browse if "full"

Tags: progress-4gl

I have a strange issue where if the browse is full of rows (but the scrollbar has not yet appeared) then the bottom row cannot be selected. Also there is no tool-tip when hovering over the bottom record.

[image]

It seems to be irrespective of the set row-height-chars and height-chars or indeed any of the properties. I only get the issue in version 10 and I cannot recreate it in version 11.

Thanks

Comment: How about using the keyboard arrow? Also, can you simulate that in an example we can run locally to try and find why/how to solve it?

Comment: @bupereira Yep the keyboard arrows/spacebar is a workaround. I've since found out progress are aware of it and don't have a solution. Will update my findings http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P178111/p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No official fix yet from Progress so I'll answer my question to that effect:
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P178111/p